# What's the theoretically fastest access to member of nullable type in C#?

Tags: c#, null, nullable

I have a field of a nullable type with a value other than `null`.
Which of the methods below is the fastest, in theory:

1. Null conditional member access

   ```
   ThisCantBeNull?.SomeMember
   ```
2. Cast to non-nullable

   ```
   ((MyType)ThisCantBeNull).SomeMember
   ```
3. Use of the `Value` member of nullable types

   ```
   ThisCantBeNull.Value.SomeMember
   ```

Note that this is only a theoretical question, such minor differences do not matter, I'm only interested in how the language works and what goes on in the background.

Comment: You wont get more than microseconds of performance out of different null checking approaches. This is a microptimization.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You haven't considered to check `HasValue`. Btw, won't the compiler optimize these? - Also note that sematics don't match. Having a default value and having an exception aren't the same thing.

Comment: And especially: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/

Comment: " I'm interested mainly in performance!" Honestly if this is a problem for performance in you app I think you have nothing to worry about. And why don't you just run tests and see if there is any difference that is the best way to see what performs best.

Comment: You're right, but pros and cons with explanation is always more informative than pure test results. I'm interested in why the results are as they are :-)

Comment: @florien You have that backwards.  Someone telling you why they think something is going to be faster is meaningless in the face of actual hard evidence that it isn't, and vice versa.

Comment: Also consider using ThisCantBeNull?.SomeMember . And you may enjoy watching https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Behind+The+Code/Rico-Mariani-Writing-better-faster-code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for curiosity:

```
public struct MyType
{
    public int SomeMember { get; set; }
}
```

Some very raw tests, **disabling compiler optimizations**:

```
MyType? thisCantBeNull = new MyType();
MyType someDefaultValue = new MyType();

var t1 = new Action(() => { var r = (thisCantBeNull ?? someDefaultValue).SomeMember; });
var t2 = new Action(() => { var r = ((MyType)thisCantBeNull).SomeMember; });
var t3 = new Action(() => { var r = thisCantBeNull.Value.SomeMember; });
var t4 = new Action(() => { var r = thisCantBeNull.GetValueOrDefault().SomeMember; });

const int times = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

var r1 = t1.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:14.45115

var r2 = t2.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:07.9415388

var r3 = t3.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:08.0096765

var r4 = t4.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:07.4732878
```

The same tests, **enabling compiler optimizations**:

```
var r1 = t1.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:02.9142143

var r2 = t2.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:02.4417182

var r3 = t3.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:02.6278304

var r4 = t4.RunNTimes(times);
// Elapsed Timespan = 00:00:02.1725020
```

Where `RunNTimes` is:

```
public static TimeSpan RunNTimes(this Action a, int nTimes = 1)
{
    if (nTimes == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("0 times not allowed", nameof(nTimes));

    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < nTimes; ++i)
        a();
    stopwatch.Stop();

    return stopwatch.Elapsed;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already checked for null elsewhere, just get the `Value`, your third option.

The other two options include an extra check.

But, as noted in the comments, the performance improvement is probably minimal.